# pcs running but status shows resources stopped

Tags: centos7, cluster

My first time setting up pcs. I have two CentOS 7 VM's on which I installed pcs and Pacemaker. I defined a virtual IP and Apache HTTP cluster.

The two VM's have IP's 192.168.56.121 and 192.168.56.122. The VIP is configured for 192.168.56.199. I can ping the VIP and can open the test index.html on the VIP.

As per another post here, I have stopped and disabled httpd.service as pcs manages its operations. firewalld is disabled as is SELinux.

I have two issues:
Firstly, my index.html on the two nodes is a single line of text saying "Node 1" and "Node 2". Refreshingly the page multiple times, I see that only the node 1 file is served unless I stop that node, in which case the file from node 2 is served. This indicates that the nodes are working as active-standby. Any way to make it a load-balancer with both nodes serving alternate requests?

Secondly, the pcs status shows that the resources are in stopped state, even though ping and http are working.

Here is what `pcs status` shows:

```
Cluster name: mycluster
Stack: corosync
Current DC: db21 (version 1.1.23-1.el7_9.1-9acf116022) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Tue Jan  5 15:47:00 2021
Last change: Tue Jan  5 11:28:04 2021 by root via cibadmin on db21

2 nodes configured
2 resource instances configured

Online: [ db21 db22 ]

Full list of resources:

 Resource Group: webgroup
     apache_res (ocf::heartbeat:apache):        Stopped
     vip_res    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Stopped

Failed Resource Actions:
* apache_res_start_0 on db21 'unknown error' (1): call=10, status=Timed Out, exitreason='',
    last-rc-change='Tue Jan  5 11:32:43 2021', queued=1ms, exec=40019ms
* apache_res_start_0 on db22 'unknown error' (1): call=10, status=Timed Out, exitreason='',
    last-rc-change='Tue Jan  5 11:33:24 2021', queued=0ms, exec=40021ms

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

Output of `pcs config show`:

```
Cluster Name: mycluster
Corosync Nodes:
 db21 db22
Pacemaker Nodes:
 db21 db22

Resources:
 Group: webgroup
  Resource: apache_res (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=apache)
   Attributes: configfile=/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf statusurl=http://127.0.0.1/server-status
   Operations: monitor interval=10s timeout=20s (apache_res-monitor-interval-10s)
               start interval=0s timeout=40s (apache_res-start-interval-0s)
               stop interval=0s timeout=60s (apache_res-stop-interval-0s)
  Resource: vip_res (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=IPaddr2)
   Attributes: cidr_netmask=24 ip=192.168.56.199
   Operations: monitor interval=10s timeout=20s (vip_res-monitor-interval-10s)
               start interval=0s timeout=20s (vip_res-start-interval-0s)
               stop interval=0s timeout=20s (vip_res-stop-interval-0s)

Stonith Devices:
Fencing Levels:

Location Constraints:
Ordering Constraints:
Colocation Constraints:
Ticket Constraints:

Alerts:
 No alerts defined

Resources Defaults:
 No defaults set
Operations Defaults:
 No defaults set

Cluster Properties:
 cluster-infrastructure: corosync
 cluster-name: mycluster
 dc-version: 1.1.23-1.el7_9.1-9acf116022
 have-watchdog: false
 stonith-enabled: false

Quorum:
  Options:
```

Which log file or command would show why the status is being shown as stopped?